# Backbone Keypress not triggering after adding template

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, backbone-views

I've created my own version of what is basically: [todomvc dependency-example](https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/blob/gh-pages/dependency-examples/backbone_require/js/views/app.js), but I built it from looking at this [Modular Backbone Example](https://github.com/thomasdavis/backbonetutorials/tree/gh-pages/examples/modular-backbone). I'm trying to move hardcoded html in the base template to it's own template file. I plan on creating multiple pages and want a minimal base template. However, when I load and insert the template in the view, the keypress event for createOnEnter stops working. Every other feature still works, which includes the other event listed in events (`clearCompleted`).

See: `this.$el.append(notesTemplate);`.

The browser never makes it to the function `createOnEnter()`.

My app view:

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'models/notes/NoteModel',
  'collections/notes/NoteCollection',
  'views/notes/NotesListView',
  'text!templates/notes/statsTemplate.html',
  'text!templates/notes/notesTemplate.html'
], function($, _, Backbone, NoteModel, NoteCollection, NotesListView, statsTemplate, notesTemplate){
  'use strict';

  var NotesView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: $("#page"),

    events: {
      "keypress #new-note":  "createOnEnter",
      "click #clear-completed": "clearCompleted"
    },

    initialize: function() {

      var onDataHandler = function(collection) {
          this.render();
      }

      this.$el.append(notesTemplate);

      this.model = new NoteCollection();
      this.model.fetch({ success : onDataHandler, dataType: "jsonp"});


      this.input = this.$("#new-note");
      this.allCheckbox = 0;

      this.listenTo(this.model, 'add', this.addOne);
      this.listenTo(this.model, 'reset', this.addAll);
      this.listenTo(this.model, 'all', this.render);

      this.footer = this.$('footer');
      this.main = $('#main');

      this.model.fetch();
    },

    render: function() {
      var done = this.model.done().length;
      var remaining = this.model.remaining().length;

      if (this.model.length) {
        this.main.show();
        this.footer.show();
        this.$('footer').show();
        this.footer.html(_.template(statsTemplate, {done: done, remaining: remaining}));
      } else {
        this.main.hide();
        this.footer.hide();
      }

      this.allCheckbox.checked = !remaining;
    },

    addOne: function(note) {
      var view = new NotesListView({model: note});
      $("#notes-list").append(view.render().el);
    },

    addAll: function() {
      this.model.each(this.addOne);
    },

    createOnEnter: function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode != 13) return;
      if (!this.input.val()) return;
      this.model.create({title: this.input.val()});
      this.input.val('');
    },

    clearCompleted: function() {
      _.invoke(this.model.done(), 'destroy');
      return false;
    },

    toggleAllComplete: function () {
      var done = this.allCheckbox.checked;
      this.model.each(function (note) { note.save({'done': done}); });
    }

  });

  return NotesView;
});
```

## Solved!

I didn't provide enough information for anyone to find the problem. It was a typo in the element with the ID `#new-note`. The above code works just fine.

Comment: Where is `that` defined? What do the templates look like? What does `#page` look like? A quick demo on jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com would be useful. PS: You should probably be using `this.collection` instead of `this.model` for collections and you probably don't want to bind to the `"all"` event like that.

Comment: Here is the [Base Template](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5954508).

Comment: `that` should have been `this`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accomplished loading templates like this by setting the `template` option in the view like this:

```
template: _.template(notesTemplate),
```

and then in my `render` function calling:

```
this.$el.html(this.template());
```

to actually render it. This ensures the events get delegated properly.

Comment: Thanks for the info. The problem turned out to be a typo, jQuery could not find the correct element to listen to.